# How to sort model in Ember.js?

Tags: ember.js

I use a model in Ember.js like this:

```
App.SomethingRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function()
  {
      return App.MyData.find();
  }
});
```

It receives data from MyData. In my data i have a field called "NAME". I would like to display data from MyData in ascendant order by NAME.

I've added a controller (thx. Toran, intuitive) like this:

```
App.SomethingController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  sortProperties: ['NAME'],
  sortAscending: true
});
```

But my template that is like this:

```
{{#each model}}
 {{NAME}}
{{/each}}
```

Still shows unordered list. How to make it right?

Comment: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.SortableMixin.html

Comment: Can you show the implementation of your find method? you need to be using ember objects (not plain JS objects) to get the binding behavior that will re-sort it on the fly

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since the `ArrayController` includes the `SortableMixin` (already mentioned in the comment from @ianpetzer), you can set the properties you want to sort on in `sortProperties`.

```
App.SomethingController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  sortProperties: ['name'],
  sortAscending: true
});
```

Comment: i've updated question because i can not make it work. Please help. thx.!

Comment: @tomaszs, there must be something else going on in your app that does not make it work, can you update you question with a jsbin/jsfiddle with your setup?

Comment: your answer helped me, i needed only to change {{#each model}} to {{#each controller}} also. thx

Comment: I had to change `controller.content` to `controller.arrangedContent` in my template in order for sorting to work.

Comment: `ArrayController` was removed in Ember 2. See my answer for an updated approach.

Answer (score 18):

`ArrayController` has been removed from Ember (v2.0) since this question was asked. Here is how you would achieve the same without using an `ArrayController`:

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  sortProperties: ['name:asc'],
  sortedModel: Ember.computed.sort('model', 'sortProperties')
});
```

And then:

```
{{#each sortedModel as |thing|}}
 {{thing.name}}
{{/each}}
```

And [here is the documentation](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.computed.html#method_sort) for Ember's computed `sort` macro.

Comment: what if I will change sorting order? How to rerender models?

Answer (score 6):

Make sure you are using {{#each controller}}, not {{#each model}}, since the Controller will have it own copy of the model collection that it sorts and presents to the template.

```
<!-- ************************************************************************ -->
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="tickets">  
<p>
<table id="tickets" class="table table-striped">
<thead>
  <tr>    
    <th {{action "sortByAttribute" "status"}}>Status</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
{{#each controller}}
    <tr>     
      <td>{{#link-to 'ticket' this.id}} {{status}} {{/link-to}} </td>
    </tr>
{{/each}}
</tbody>
</table>  
</p>
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
App.SomethingController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    sortProperties: ['name'],
    sortAscending: true 
});
```

Make sure your find method does something like this

```
App.Person.reopenClass({
    people: [],
    find: function() {
        var self = this;
        $.getJSON('/api/people', function(response) {
            response.forEach(function(hash) {
                var person = App.Person.create(hash);
                Ember.run(self.people, self.people.pushObject, person);
            });
        }, this);
        return this.people;
    }
});
```

Not this (this will not update the template via binding because it's a vanilla JS object instead of a full blown ember object)

```
App.Person.reopenClass({
    people: [],
    find: function() {
        var self = this;
        $.getJSON('/api/people', function(response) {
            response.forEach(function(hash) {
                Ember.run(self.people, self.people.pushObject, hash);
            });
        }, this);
        return this.people;
    }
});
```

Comment: i've updated question because i can not make it work. Please help. thx.