# Ember: What is the non controller way to sort an array of models

Tags: ember.js

I want to sort an array of Ember models by date but but it seems like all of the old documentation is related to sorting inside a controller. In this case I need to sort this array when I get the model in a route so I can send it to a service to have an action performed on it.

I have two models, site and flight.

so I have an object site whose constructor is is `myApp@model:site`

and I want to get an array of flight objects related to that site in a has many configuration sorted by date.

my attempt was:

`var flights = site.get('flights').sortBy('executeAt:desc');`

One weird thing I noticed is that without the ":desc" it defaults to ascending

`var flights = site.get('flights').sortBy('executeAt');` -> ascending

But the value of what is after the colon doesn't affect anything

`var flights = site.get('flights').sortBy('executeAt:');` -> descending
or
``var flights = site.get('flights').sortBy('executeAt:asc');` -> descending

And in some case it messes up the sort entirely and gives me unsorted data.

For reference, date format is : `2015-09-03T13:34:33.000Z`

So what is the best way to get a sorted list of this data?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your best bet is to use `Ember.computed.sort`. Here are the API docs: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.computed.html#method_sort

Example:

```
// components/site-widget.js
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  // The site model
  site: null,

  // List of flights
  flights: Ember.computed.alias('site.flights'),

  // Flights sorted in order
  sortedFlights: Ember.computed.sort('flights', '_flightSorting')
  _flightSorting: ['executeAt:desc']
});
```

Usage:

```
// templates/sites.hbs
{{#each sites as |site|}}
  {{site-widget site=site}}
{{/each}}
```

In that case the `_flightStoring` property is actually observed and mutable. Changing it's value will also change the sort order.

---

If you wanted to do your own custom sorting, you can use it as an a/b function. For example:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  /* ... */

  sortedFlights: Ember.computed.sort('flights', function(a, b) {
    return a.executeAt > b.executeAt;
  })
});
```

---

I'd like to take this opportunity to shamelessly plug my Ember addon for `Ember.computed.sortBy`. If you don't need mutable sorting, I'd recommend you check it out. https://github.com/workmanw/ember-computed-sortby

I also have an open RFC and am hopefully this will be adopted into Ember core. https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/pull/87

---

UPDATE: I've created an Ember Twiddle to help demonstrate the entire thing: http://ember-twiddle.com/60efa60e191fa9026774

I might have gotten slightly carried away building the app. But the files that are relevant to your question are "components/flight-list.js" and "templates/components/site.hbs".

Comment: I'm doing this at the route level. I actually tried to set a computed property on a controller from a route but no luck. If you are familiar with that I would be very interested to hear.

Comment: Yes, this is what the `setupController` hook on the route is for. I can cook you up an EmberFiddle shortly.

Comment: @Andrew -- I might have got a little carried away, but I tried to build you an entire robust example of your app. See here: http://ember-twiddle.com/60efa60e191fa9026774

Answer (score 1):

I haven't associated multiple models yet, but this is the > 2.0 way to deal with sorting - after the sortable mixin was deprecated.

```
var SomeCollection = Ember.Object.extend({
  content: [],
  sortProperties: ['someProperty:desc'],
  sortedContent: Ember.computed.sort('content', 'sortProperties'),
});
```

http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.computed.html#method_sort

Maybe this will help.  : )

*Maybe not for arrays though*... and then what you already have: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Array.html#method_sortBy

Comment: This seems like it could work. Let me give it a go and I will report back.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sort your models in the route directly, you could do:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    this.store.findAll('model-name', {reload: true})
              .then(model => model.sortBy('attributeName'));
  }
});
```

(Credit goes to torazaburo - [How to sort model using only a route in ember?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31318282/how-to-sort-model-using-only-a-route-in-ember))

And for descending order simply add `.reverse()` to the array:

```
             ...
              .then(model => model.sortBy('attributeName').reverse());
```